# сложить два массива

Tags: php, массивы, циклы

В цикле собираю массива такого формата:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 03.2019
        [1] => 620000
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 03.2019
        [1] => 138269.56
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 03.2019
        [1] => 430015.2
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 02.2019
        [1] => 643331.99
    )

)
```

как сделать сравнение значений `[0] => 03.2019` и если они одинаковые сложить все значения `[1] => 620000` ?

т/е в данном примере три одинаковые даты вот и надо сложить между собой `[1] => 620000 + [1] => 138269.56 + [1] => 430015.2`

Answer (score 0):

Я бы советовал ключи добавлять вместо индексного массива, может поламаться всё случайно, но я бы сделал вот так:

```
$array = [
    [
        '03.2019', '620000'
    ],
    [
        '03.2019', '138269.56'
    ],
    [
        '03.2019', '430015.2'
    ],
    [
        '02.2019', '643331.99'
    ]
];

$result = [];
foreach ($array as $item) {
    [$date, $amount] = $item;
    if (empty($result[$date])) {
        $result[$date] = [$date, $amount];
    }

    $result[$date][1] += $amount;
}

var_dump(array_values($result)); // Если ключи не важны, можно убрать array_values
```

На выходе получаем:

```
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  array(2) {
    [0] =>
    string(7) "03.2019"
    [1] =>
    double(1808284.76)
  }
  [1] =>
  array(2) {
    [0] =>
    string(7) "02.2019"
    [1] =>
    double(1286663.98)
  }
}
```

Comment: спасибо за натырку!